# Regex group capture in R with multiple capture-groups

Tags: regex, r, capture, capture-group

In R, is it possible to extract group capture from a regular expression match?  As far as I can tell, none of `grep`, `grepl`, `regexpr`, `gregexpr`, `sub`, or `gsub` return the group captures.

I need to extract key-value pairs from strings that are encoded thus:

```
\((.*?) :: (0\.[0-9]+)\)
```

I can always just do multiple full-match greps, or do some outside (non-R) processing, but I was hoping I can do it all within R.  Is there's a function or a package that provides such a function to do this?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`str_match()`, from the [`stringr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package, will do this. It returns a character matrix with one column for each group in the match (and one for the whole match):

```
> s = c("(sometext :: 0.1231313213)", "(moretext :: 0.111222)")
> str_match(s, "\\((.*?) :: (0\\.[0-9]+)\\)")
     [,1]                         [,2]       [,3]          
[1,] "(sometext :: 0.1231313213)" "sometext" "0.1231313213"
[2,] "(moretext :: 0.111222)"     "moretext" "0.111222"
```

Comment: and `str_match_all()` to match all groups in a regex

Comment: How can I just print only the captured groups for [,1] ?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. The captured groups are columns 2 & 3. `[,1]` is the full match. `[,2:3]` is the captured groups.

Answer (score 67):

gsub does this, from your example:

```
gsub("\\((.*?) :: (0\\.[0-9]+)\\)","\\1 \\2", "(sometext :: 0.1231313213)")
[1] "sometext 0.1231313213"
```

you need to double escape the \s in the quotes then they work for the regex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I need to pull out the captured substrings to put in a data.frame.  But, looking at your answer, I guess I could chain gsub and a couple of strsplit's to get what I want, maybe:

strsplit(strsplit(gsub(regex, "\\1::\\2::::", str), "::::")[[1]], "::")

Comment: Great. The R `gsub` manpage very badly needs an example showing you need '\\1' to escape a capture-group reference.

Answer (score 46):

Try `regmatches()` and `regexec()`:

```
regmatches("(sometext :: 0.1231313213)",regexec("\\((.*?) :: (0\\.[0-9]+)\\)","(sometext :: 0.1231313213)"))
[[1]]
[1] "(sometext :: 0.1231313213)" "sometext"                   "0.1231313213"
```

Comment: Thanks for the vanilla R solution and for pointing out `regmatches` which I've never seen before

Comment: Why would you have to write the string twice?

Comment: @StefanoBorini `regexec` returns a list holding information regarding only the location of the matches, hence `regmatches` requires the user to provide the string the match list belonged to.

Comment: @andy wait until you hear about [strcapture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45851537/1870254)

Answer (score 21):

gsub() can do this and return only the capture group:

However, in order for this to work, you must explicitly select elements outside your capture group as mentioned in the gsub() help.

> (...) elements of character vectors 'x' which are not substituted will be returned unchanged.

So if your text to be selected lies in the middle of some string, adding .* before and after the capture group should allow you to only return it.

`gsub(".*\\((.*?) :: (0\\.[0-9]+)\\).*","\\1 \\2", "(sometext :: 0.1231313213)")
    [1] "sometext 0.1231313213"`

Answer (score 8):

Solution with `strcapture` from the `utils`:

```
x <- c("key1 :: 0.01",
       "key2 :: 0.02")
strcapture(pattern = "(.*) :: (0\\.[0-9]+)",
           x = x,
           proto = list(key = character(), value = double()))
#>    key value
#> 1 key1  0.01
#> 2 key2  0.02
```

Comment: This is the right way to do stuff like this. Allows using PCRE and forces you to be explicit about expected column types & names.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I ended up working around this problem.  I used two separate regexes to match the first and second capture groups and run two `gregexpr` calls, then pull out the matched substrings:

```
regex.string <- "(?<=\\().*?(?= :: )"
regex.number <- "(?<= :: )\\d\\.\\d+"

match.string <- gregexpr(regex.string, str, perl=T)[[1]]
match.number <- gregexpr(regex.number, str, perl=T)[[1]]

strings <- mapply(function (start, len) substr(str, start, start+len-1),
                  match.string,
                  attr(match.string, "match.length"))
numbers <- mapply(function (start, len) as.numeric(substr(str, start, start+len-1)),
                  match.number,
                  attr(match.number, "match.length"))
```

Comment: +1 for a working code. However, I'd rather run a quick shell command from R and use a Bash one-liner like this `expr "xyx0.0023xyxy" : '[^0-9]*\([.0-9]\+\)'`

Answer (score 4):

I like perl compatible regular expressions. Probably someone else does too...

Here is a function that does perl compatible regular expressions and matches the functionality of functions in other languages that I am used to:

```
regexpr_perl <- function(expr, str) {
  match <- regexpr(expr, str, perl=T)
  matches <- character(0)
  if (attr(match, 'match.length') >= 0) {
    capture_start <- attr(match, 'capture.start')
    capture_length <- attr(match, 'capture.length')
    total_matches <- 1 + length(capture_start)
    matches <- character(total_matches)
    matches[1] <- substr(str, match, match + attr(match, 'match.length') - 1)
    if (length(capture_start) > 1) {
      for (i in 1:length(capture_start)) {
        matches[i + 1] <- substr(str, capture_start[[i]], capture_start[[i]] + capture_length[[i]] - 1)
      }
    }
  }
  matches
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the [`stringr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package, this can be achieved using either `str_match()` or `str_extract()`.

Adapted from the manual:

```
library(stringr)

strings <- c(" 219 733 8965", "329-293-8753 ", "banana", 
             "239 923 8115 and 842 566 4692",
             "Work: 579-499-7527", "$1000",
             "Home: 543.355.3679")
phone <- "([2-9][0-9]{2})[- .]([0-9]{3})[- .]([0-9]{4})"
```

Extracting and combining our groups:

```
str_extract_all(strings, phone, simplify=T)
#      [,1]           [,2]          
# [1,] "219 733 8965" ""            
# [2,] "329-293-8753" ""            
# [3,] ""             ""            
# [4,] "239 923 8115" "842 566 4692"
# [5,] "579-499-7527" ""            
# [6,] ""             ""            
# [7,] "543.355.3679" ""
```

Indicating groups with an output matrix (we're interested in columns 2+):

```
str_match_all(strings, phone)
# [[1]]
#      [,1]           [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  
# [1,] "219 733 8965" "219" "733" "8965"
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1]           [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  
# [1,] "329-293-8753" "329" "293" "8753"
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# 
# [[4]]
#      [,1]           [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  
# [1,] "239 923 8115" "239" "923" "8115"
# [2,] "842 566 4692" "842" "566" "4692"
# 
# [[5]]
#      [,1]           [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  
# [1,] "579-499-7527" "579" "499" "7527"
# 
# [[6]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# 
# [[7]]
#      [,1]           [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  
# [1,] "543.355.3679" "543" "355" "3679"
```

Comment: what about 842 566 4692

Comment: Thanks for catching the omission. Corrected using the `_all` suffix for the relevant `stringr` functions.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the package *unglue*, taking the example from the selected answer:

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)

s <- c("(sometext :: 0.1231313213)", "(moretext :: 0.111222)")
unglue_data(s, "({x} :: {y})")
#>          x            y
#> 1 sometext 0.1231313213
#> 2 moretext     0.111222
```

Or starting from a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(col = s)
unglue_unnest(df, col, "({x} :: {y})",remove = FALSE)
#>                          col        x            y
#> 1 (sometext :: 0.1231313213) sometext 0.1231313213
#> 2     (moretext :: 0.111222) moretext     0.111222
```

you can get the raw regex from the unglue pattern, optionally with named capture :

```r
unglue_regex("({x} :: {y})")
#>             ({x} :: {y}) 
#> "^\\((.*?) :: (.*?)\\)$"

unglue_regex("({x} :: {y})",named_capture = TRUE)
#>                     ({x} :: {y}) 
#> "^\\((?<x>.*?) :: (?<y>.*?)\\)$"
```

More info : https://github.com/moodymudskipper/unglue/blob/master/README.md