# Regular expression is not working as expected

Tags: regex

Could some one help me regular expression for this. I am really struggling.

Basically i want to write a regular expression to separate the string into two sub strings.

For example in the example i want to separate the full string into `"comp99810_c0_seq1" and "|m.8409"`.

```
test <- "comp99810_c0_seq1|m.8409" 
c1 <- sub("([A-Za-z1-9])(\\|)(m.\\d+)", "\\1", test) 
c2 <- sub("([A-Za-z1-9])(\\|)(m.\\d+)", "\\2\\3", test)
```

I was able to get c1 to work but not c2. Can somebody help me....

Thanks 
Upendra

Comment: What programming language is this?  Doesn't it have a `split` function that you can use to split on `|`?

Comment: What is the separator? Just `|`? What is the expected pattern of both sides?

Comment: Define "won't work" you are using the same regex, how is one "not working"? Also, what host language are you using? It looks like R?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex group capture in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952275/regex-group-capture-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use similar `split("|")` function from the language you are currently it is using.

However, change the `[A-Za-z1-9]` into `\\w+` and it will work for you.

Currently your regex meaning only one character. Whereas the `\\w+` means 1 or more characters from `a-zA-Z`, `0-9`, `_`

Comment: I did this instead and it worked... `c1 <- sub("(\\w+\\d+)(\\|)(m.\\d+)", "\\1", test)` and `c2 <- sub("(\\w+\\d+)(\\|)(m.\\d+)", "\\2\\3", test)`. Thanks for the hint though...

Comment: The `\\d+` will hurt you when the input is like `comp99810_c0_seq|m.8409`. Try now! and after that remove that `\\d+` kindly and try again :-)

Comment: You are right. Eventhough i have only the kind that have both words and numbers and `\\d+` works i don't needed it. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to split on "\|", the issue is the first group is missing a repeat character. i.e. ([A-Za-z1-9])+ or ([A-Za-z1-9])*. Because now it is only matching a single character in that set then trying to find the pipe.

Comment: I don't want to split based n "|" as i still want to keep that in the captured group.