# Access regex group results by name using gregexpr in R

Tags: c#, r, regex, grouping

How can I access all matches with groupings (i.e. `label`) using `gregexpr()`in R?

```
s <- "aaa123bbb345ccc"
p <- "(?<label>\\d+)"
m <- gregexpr(p, s, perl = TRUE)
```

I am interested in printing the matches in m but referencing the group name `<label1>`. This can be easily done in C# but I'm struggling in R and I cannot figure out how to do this from the CRAN docs.

Edit: C# code below requested by [G Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck):

```
string s = "aaa123bbb345ccc";
string p = @"(?<label>\d+)";
Regex r = new Regex(p);
Match m = r.Match(s);
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["label"].Value);
}
```

Comment: ["The best way to use regular expressions with R is to pass the perl=TRUE parameter. This tells R to use the PCRE regular expressions library."](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)

Comment: See `?regmatches`

Comment: Can you use `["label"]` ?

Comment: `regmatches(s, m)` or avoid the awkward two-function approach with `stringr::str_extract_all(s, p)`

Comment: When you use `gregexpr` with `regmatches`, only matches are preserved. The easiest is to use stringr `str_match_all`. `regexec` could be an alternative, but it does not work with PCRE regexps.

Comment: Maybe a dupe of [Regex group capture in R with multiple capture-groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952275/regex-group-capture-in-r-with-multiple-capture-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return only the substrings associated with `label`.

```
st <- attr(m[[1]], "capture.start")[, "label"]
len <- attr(m[[1]], "capture.length")[, "label"]
substring(s, st, st + len - 1)
## [1] "123" "345"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close. I'm getting an "Error in capture.start[, "label"] : subscript out of bounds".

Comment: I have revised the answer a few times. Check the latest one.  It works for me if run after the code supplied in the question.

Comment: It works! This is what I was looking for. I wish this would be easier in R like it is in C# but it provides what I need.

Comment: Can you add some code at the bottom of your question providing an example of C# code that does it.