# Regex Capturing \" in R

Tags: r, regex

I have some data with height strings which are formatted like so

```
"6'2\""
```

I'm capturing the first digit just fine, but I can't get rid of the

```
\"
```

from the end of the string

I've tried several ways of getting at it but nothing has worked yet. Here's where I'm currently at

```
inches <- str_extract(htString,"(\\d{1,2})[\\\"]?$")

[1] "11"
[1] "3\""
```

If the inches string is 2 digits long, I'm able to capture the right characters, otherwise, I'm capturing the \"

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
Thanks for the help. The following code ended up working for me. It could be cleaned up I'm sure.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(hs)){
  htString <- hs[i,]$HtRec

  ft <- str_extract(htString, "^(\\d{1,2})[\']?")
  ft <- substring(ft, 1, 1)

  inches <- str_extract(htString,"(\\d{1,2})[\"]?$")
  inches <- str_extract_all(inches, "\\d+")

  ft <- as.numeric(ft)
  inches <- as.numeric(inches)
  htInches <- (ft * 12) + inches
  hs[i,]$HtRec <- htInches
}
```

Comment: The output you see may not be literal.  What I mean by this is that in `[1] "3\""` R is itself escaping the double quotes.  In fact, there may not even be any backslashes in your data at all.  To confirm this, just write the data frame to a text file and check.

Comment: I imagine Tim is right. You literally have the text string `6'2"`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think that is the case because if i do `as.numeric(inches)` then I get back NAs. edit: Oh, I see what you're saying. I'm not capturing the last `"` correctly then.

Comment: `as.numeric("text")` always gives `NA` - you don't have a number so you get `NA`

Comment: @ZachFisher No...this is expected.  Would you expect `as.numeric` with a quote in the input to be castable to a number?  The slash is irrelevant; it won't work.

Comment: `str_extract_all(x, "\\d+")` is what you want I think.

Comment: @thelatemail that worked thanks!

Comment: @ZachFisher - feel free to answer and accept your own question. You get a couple of points of karma and the question gets closed off. Win-win :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in R, but If I try:

```
(\d+).(\d+)
```

on https://regex101.com/ with test string: `"65'2\""` it seems that I can match both numbers:

> Group 1.  1-3 `65`
>
> Group 2.  4-5 `2`

This uses the concept of capture groups. It seems that `str_match()` will help you for working with capture groups, take a look at: [Regex group capture in R with multiple capture-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952275/regex-group-capture-in-r-with-multiple-capture-groups/953496)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The following code ended up working for me using @thelatemail's answer. It could be cleaned up for sure.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(hs)){
  htString <- hs[i,]$HtRec

  ft <- str_extract(htString, "^(\\d{1,2})[\']?")
  ft <- substring(ft, 1, 1)

  inches <- str_extract(htString,"(\\d{1,2})[\"]?$")
  inches <- str_extract_all(inches, "\\d+")

  ft <- as.numeric(ft)
  inches <- as.numeric(inches)
  htInches <- (ft * 12) + inches
  hs[i,]$HtRec <- htInches
}
```