# Extracting Sub-expressions from a Dataframe of Strings Using Regular Expressions

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a regular expression that is able to match my data, using `grepl`, but I can't figure out how to extract the sub-expressions inside it to new columns.

This is returning the test string as `foo`, without any of the sub-expressions:

```
entryPattern <- "(\\d+)\\s+([[:lower:][:blank:]-]*[A-Z][[:alpha:][:blank:]-]+[A-Z]\\s[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+)\\s+([A-Z]{3})\\s+(\\d{4})\\s+(\\d\\d\\-\\d\\d)\\s+([[:print:][:blank:]]+)\\s+(\\d*\\:?\\d+\\.\\d+)"
test <- "101      POULET Laure                               FRA     1992   25-29     E. M. S. Bron Natation          26.00"
m <- regexpr(entryPattern, test)
foo <- regmatches(test, m)
```

In my real use case, I'm acting on lots of strings similar to `test`.  I'm able to find the correctly formatted ones, so I think the pattern is correct.

```
rows$isMatch <- grepl(entryPattern, rows$text)
```

What 'm hoping to do is add the sub-expressions as new columns in the rows dataframe (i.e. `rows$rank`, `rows$name`, `rows$country`, etc.).  *Thanks in advance for any advice.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `regmatches` won't do what I want.  Instead, I need the stringr package, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10038710/1811952) by @kent-johnson.

```
library(stringr)
test <- "101      POULET Laure                               FRA     1992   25-29     E. M. S. Bron Natation          26.00"
entryPattern <- "(\\d+)\\s+([[:lower:][:blank:]-]*[A-Z][[:alpha:][:blank:]-]+[A-Z]\\s[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+?)\\s+([A-Z]{3})\\s+(\\d{4})\\s+(\\d\\d\\-\\d\\d)\\s+([[:print:][:blank:]]+?)\\s+(\\d*\\:?\\d+\\.\\d+)"
str_match(test, entryPattern)[1,2:8]
```

Which outputs:

```
[1] "101"                            
[2] "POULET Laure"                   
[3] "FRA"                            
[4] "1992"                           
[5] "25-29"                          
[6] "E. M. S. Bron Natation"
[7] "26.00"
```