# converting the 13-,4- to -13,-4 using regular expression?

Tags: r, regex

So I have a text column in data frame:

```
stocksavailable

140,13-,3-,40-,2-
```

The numbers 13-, 2- and 3- are incorrect while extracting, can we get something like this using R code?

```
stocksavailable
140,-13,-3,-40,-2
```

Comment: What have you tried?. also if you want an answer in R please tag it to your question to attract more accurate attention

Comment: have you tried any thing, so please share your result so anyone can suggest based on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the numbers are integers, try: `(\d+)(\-)?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fGTrX3/1/)

You should be able to use the gsub method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953496/9534819)

Comment: It worked : in R I did this

ptn<- "(\\d+)(\\-)?"
string = "140,13-,3-,40-,2-"

subst = "\\2\\1"

gsub(ptn,subst,string)