# Split a string into lines based on regex of one or more words followed by two numeric values

Tags: r, regex

Give a string such as this:

```
x <- c("Carroll 103 215 Albany City 24 41 Allegany 115 231 Charlotte 116 248")
```

What's the best way to split this into lines such as this:

```
# [1] Carroll 103 215
# [2] Albany City 24 41
# [3] Allegany 115 231
# [4] Charlotte 116 248
```

It's the "Albany City" that is giving me trouble. There are other words too that will contain one or more words, (e.g. "Port Jervis City"), however, these should always be followed by numeric values of length 1 or more.

Comment: Maybe try something like `str_extract_all(x,"([A-Za-z]+ )+(\\d+ )+")` with the `stringr` package.

Comment: @Nicola this works but returns trailing space and also misses the last numeric value for Charlotte.

Comment: Try with `([A-Za-z]+ )+(\\d+ ?)+`.

Comment: Can there be any non-ASCII letters (with accents)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, always ASCII, and there will always be exactly two numbers, although a more flexible solution would be preferred.

Comment: Try `regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z ]*\\d[ \\d]*\\b", x, perl=TRUE))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z ]*(?:\\s?\\d+)*\\b", x, perl=TRUE))` ?

Comment: @AndreElrico 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?strsplit` from normal R

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=\\d)\\s(?=[A-Za-z])", perl = T)[[1]]
```

or

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=\\d)\\s(?=\\D)", perl = T)[[1]] # less explizit, but much cooler
```

for both

```
#[1] "Carroll 103 215"   "Albany City 24 41" "Allegany 115 231"  "Charlotte 116 248"
```

data:

```
x = "Carroll 103 215 Albany City 24 41 Allegany 115 231 Charlotte 116 248"
```

---

learn more?:

https://regex101.com/r/7cUESK/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract_all` that finds all regex matches in a string with a regex:

```
[A-Za-z ]+(\s\d+)+\s?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4MlO3q/3/)

Explanation:

- `[A-Za-z ]+` matches any number of words separated by spaces
- `(\s\d+)+` numbers separates by whitespaces
- `\s?` final (possible) whitespace

Comment: This works but returns a leading space (which I can certainly handle after the fact) for all results except the first one

Comment: Some grouping may help, `([A-Za-z ]+\s\d+\s\d+)\s?` detailsshown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952275/regex-group-capture-in-r-with-multiple-capture-groups

Comment: This solution works only if each name is followed by exactly two numbers.

Comment: you can add `\w` to the start of the patern to exclude the tailing space https://regex101.com/r/4MlO3q/2

Comment: @nicola: extened to support any number of numbers