# Is there an R function to extract all numbers followed by specific pattern?

Tags: r, string, extract

I am working R. I want to extract all numbers between the last blank space and a string pattern ("-APPLE") in a vector. The numbers can be of variable length.

```
test_string = c("ABC 2-APPLE", "123 25-APPLE", "DEF GHI 567-APPLE", "ORANGE")
```

Expected Result set should be a vector as in  c(2, 25, 567, NA)

Answer (score 1):

See [Regex group capture in R with multiple capture-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952275/regex-group-capture-in-r-with-multiple-capture-groups) for an example of using `str_match()`, from the [`stringr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package.

In your case:

```
> test_string = c("ABC 2-APPLE", "123 25-APPLE", "DEF GHI 567-APPLE")
> 
> library(stringr)
> x <- str_match(test_string, " ([0-9]+)-APPLE$")[,2]
> as.numeric(x)
[1]   2  25 567
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.
Two  followup questions:
1.Can you help me understand the the significance of the $ character?
2. why are there 2 columns in output of str_match function (i.e. in object x)?

Comment: 1. [What does the $ (dollar) sign in a regex pattern mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877408/what-does-the-dollar-sign-in-a-regex-pattern-mean) 2. [`str_match`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_match) "First column is the complete match, followed by one column for each capture group."

Answer (score 1):

you can use the "rebus" package, which is very user-friendly in creating the regex patterns you need.

```r
library(rebus)
## adjust the lo and hi arguments of dgt() based on your text

rx <- lookbehind(SPACE) %R% dgt(1,5) %R% lookahead("-APPLE")
str_extract(test_string, rx)
```